# How to call a setter method with arguments dynamically in flash AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, function-calls

This AS3 function works for normal methods and getter methods:

```
   public function MyClassTestAPI(functionName:String, ...rest):* {
    var value:*;            
        try {
            switch(rest.length) {
                case 0:
                    value = myObj[functionName];
                    break;
                case 1:
                    value = myObj[functionName].call(functionName, rest[0]);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    value = myObj[functionName].call(functionName, rest[0],rest[1]);
                    break;
                default:
                    throw("Cannot pass more than 2 parameters (passed " + rest.length + ")");
            }                
        } 
        return value;                
    }
```

Sample usage:

```
this.MyClassTestAPI("Foo", "arg1"); // tests function Foo(arg1:String):String
this.MyClassTestAPI("MyProperty");  // tests function get MyProperty():String
this.MyClassTestAPI("MyProperty", "new value");// tests function set MyProperty(val:String):void
```

The third call does not work (throws exception).
How can I make it work for setter methods as well?
Thanks!

edit:
This is a version that works, except with getter and setter that have additional parameters.
It is ok for my needs:

```
   public function MyClassTestAPI(functionName:String, ...rest):* {
    var value:*;            
        try {
            if (typeof(this.mediaPlayer[functionName]) == 'function') {
                switch(rest.length) {
                case 0:
                    value = myObj[functionName].call(functionName);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    value = myObj[functionName].call(functionName, rest[0]);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    value = myObj[functionName].call(functionName, rest[0],rest[1]);
                    break;
                default:
                    throw("Cannot pass more than 2 parameters (passed " + rest.length + ")");
                }                
            }  else {
                switch(rest.length) {
                case 0:
                    value = myObj[functionName];
                    break;
                case 1:
                    myObj[functionName] = rest[0];
                    break;
                default:
                    throw("Cannot pass parameter to getter or more than one parameter to setter (passed " + rest.length + ")");
               }                
            }
        } 
        return value;                
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setter functions works as variables, so you can't use it in this way:

```
    myProperty.call( "new value" );
```

Your function for variables is pointless, because you just have to do a value assignment:

```
    myProperty = "new value";
```

By the way you can include it in your function in two ways:

1. create a third parameter what tells your function it is a function or variable
2. create the value assignment in the catch section

Comment: This is the correct reason for the error, although I've been trying to do a detection for a setter versus a function and even using try...catches the compiler gets upset about both approaches being in the code.

Comment: This maybe helps you:
flash.utils.describeType( objectWhichOwnsThePropertyOrFunction )
It gives back an XML, what contains all of the public properties and methods of the object.

Comment: I accepted your answer, but used typeof to guess if it is a getter/setter. I added a solution in my question.  Thanks!                                                             I will post another question on cancelling the switch.

Answer (score 0):

You are currently passing only one string with value "new value"

This should do the trick:

```
this.MyClassTestAPI("MyProperty", "new","value");
```

For more information on this matter check the Adobe LiveDocs at:
http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=03_Language_and_Syntax_19.html

Cheers